# PHP upgrade 5.6 to 7.2 result in segfault

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.4

I upgrade one of my Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS server from PHP 5.6 to 7.2.
I use Ondrej PPA : https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

After the upgrade, I found some segmentation fault with production traffic ...

I try to use gdb with coredump but don't really understand it :

```
#0  0x00007ff113f35542 in zend_update_class_constants () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#1  0x00007ff113f35563 in zend_update_class_constants () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#2  0x00007ff113f35cc1 in _object_and_properties_init () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#3  0x00007ff113fd4e1c in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#4  0x00007ff113fde90b in execute_ex () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#5  0x00007ff113fe4d1e in zend_execute () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#6  0x00007ff113f331e3 in zend_execute_scripts () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#7  0x00007ff113ece330 in php_execute_script () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#8  0x00007ff113fe6ed2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so
#9  0x00005562052ef140 in ap_run_handler ()
#10 0x00005562052ef6c6 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#11 0x0000556205305e2c in ap_internal_redirect ()
#12 0x00007ff10fdfaa92 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
#13 0x00005562052ef140 in ap_run_handler ()
#14 0x00005562052ef6c6 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#15 0x0000556205305e2c in ap_internal_redirect ()
#16 0x00007ff10fdfaa92 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
#17 0x00005562052ef140 in ap_run_handler ()
#18 0x00005562052ef6c6 in ap_invoke_handler ()
#19 0x0000556205306ba2 in ap_process_async_request ()
#20 0x0000556205306d50 in ap_process_request ()
#21 0x0000556205302e1e in ?? ()
#22 0x00005562052f90f0 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#23 0x00007ff1145537e9 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#24 0x00007ff114553a74 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#25 0x00007ff114553aeb in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#26 0x00007ff114554ac7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#27 0x00005562052d179e in ap_run_mpm ()
#28 0x00005562052ca690 in main ()
```

I use Apache 2.4.18 with PHP 7.2.13 with Pecl packages :

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package  Version State
amqp     1.9.4   stable
igbinary 2.0.8   stable
mongodb  1.4.4   stable
oauth    2.0.3   stable
redis    4.2.0   stable
zmq      1.1.3   beta
```

I also use NewRelic PHP Agent, full list of installed PHP packages :

```
php-common/xenial,xenial,now 2:69+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all  [installé, automatique]
php-pear/xenial,xenial,now 1:1.10.6+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 all  [installé, automatique]
php-xml/xenial,xenial,now 2:7.2+69+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all  [installé, automatique]
php7.2/xenial,xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all  [installé]
php7.2-bcmath/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-cli/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
php7.2-common/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
php7.2-curl/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-dev/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-gd/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-json/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
php7.2-mbstring/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-mysql/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-opcache/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
php7.2-pspell/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-readline/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
php7.2-soap/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-tidy/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
php7.2-xml/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé, automatique]
php7.2-zip/xenial,now 7.2.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64  [installé]
```

To migrate my PHP, I remove and purge packages and Pecl packages ...

I'm starting to think that I may have done a bad job during migration ...
If someone can help me ...

Comment: Did you upgrade Apache from the same source?

Comment: Yes, I already use Ondrej PPA

Answer (score 0):

Could you switch to `LogLevel debug` in your http.conf and post the output? This will show you the PID that executes right before the segmentation fault. In my case, Dynatrace was causing `mod_authz_core` to segfault. More than likely, it is a dependency being used by a separate process causing the issue.